# Semantic UI React: fixed sidebar & header

Tags: javascript, reactjs, semantic-ui-react

I'm trying to create a header and sidebar where the header sits just left of the sidebar and not overlayed like the image below.

[image: Sidebar Overlay on Header]

I've created the Sidebar and Header components separately in different files and am importing both to render into an App.js file like below:

*App.js:*

```
render() {    
  return (    
    <div className='fp-wrapper'>
        <AppSidebar />
          <div className='fp-panel-main'>
            <AppHeader />
        </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

The issue is that the two components are being rendered ontop of each other (see screenshot). Is there any way to build these components separately and have them fit together?

I have found that one way to solve this is to build the components directly to the sidebar (see Sidebar.Pusher & text Stuff) which is rendered correctly sitting right of the sidebar whereas the header is being overlapped.

*Sidebar:*

```
render() {
  const { activeItem } = this.state
  return (
    <Sidebar.Pusher>    
      <Sidebar
        as={Menu}
        animation='push'
        direction='left'
        icon='labeled'
        inverted
        visible='true'
        vertical
        width='thin'
      >
      <Menu.Item as='a'>
        <Icon name='home' />
        Lexis
      </Menu.Item>
      <Menu.Item as='a'>
        Page 1
      </Menu.Item>
      <Menu.Item as='a'>
        Page 2
      </Menu.Item>
      </Sidebar>

      <Sidebar.Pusher>  
             Stuff
      </Sidebar.Pusher>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to do it would be wrapping the `<AppSidebar>` in a `<div className="sidebar">` and use `display: flex` to display them side by side, like this.

```
render(){
  return (
    <div className='fp-wrapper'>
      <div className="sidebar">
        <AppSidebar />
      </div>
      <div className='fp-panel-main'>
        <AppHeader />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

and add CSS to that

```
.fp-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap; //This will keep the layout at all screen sizes.
}
.sidebar {
  width: 30%;
}
.fp-panel-main {
  width: 70%;
}
```

**Note:** You can also add a className or id to `<SideBar.Pusher>` and you wouldn't need to wrap the `<AppSideBar />` with the `<div className="sidebar">`.

Comment: Thanks, this method worked! Except that setting a % width for .sidebar{} did not adjust properly for window resizing. Instead I used 'min-width' with 'em' units.